# CSS Font Import Assistance

Tags: css

I'm attempting to import a font from a local file into my website; however, it does not appear to like what I have. Below is a snippet of my font import:

```
@font-face{
font-family: Avenir;
src: url("Avenir.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

I've tried having the text file saved in the root as well as in a "fonts" folder and then referenced with "fonts/Avenir.ttf", but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you are not running a server to serve up static files, or web pack to prepackage things, you might need a full url with `http://mysite.example.com/fonts/Avenir.ttf`.  This depends a lot on how your page/app is deployed and who is serving up the assets.

Comment: I'm currently just testing through my machine/text editor. Outside of that, I'm publicly testing it out through my github at https://santrapgamer.github.io/. I currently don't have the font saved on there, but I can gladly at it to my github if you would prefer for a further look at things?

Comment: How are you applying the fonts? In addition to calling out ```@font-family``` you must do something like ```body { font-family: "Avenir" }``` to apply them to the body or to specific elements. Can you add all the relevant CSS code to your question?

Comment: `/* General page styling. */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

@CarltonLindsay This is the CSS that I have in place that is supposed to call the font.